# How shadow a file to point to something else?

Tags: virtualbox, file-sharing, shadow

**Case:**

- VirtualBox doesn't support Windows' symlink to be [shared](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10261) with host (Linux).
- actually a physical folder which contains the link is share. Everything except the symlink can be accessed.
- Have a symlink in that folder is currently the easiest for my purpose (describing the situation is not feasible). Other options are too length and chances of error are high.
- when the VB shared folder is mounted (`sudo mount -t vboxsf foo /home/apache/foo -o rw`) the symlink (`bar`) it contains is listed but it's content can't be viewed. `file /home/apache/foo/bar` returns an error saying something like

> /home/apache/foo/bar: broken symbolic link to `X:\foo\bar'
>
> What I can do is VB share the link to which `bar` links to and mount it at say `~/mounts/bar`.

**Question:**

How can I shadow `~/foo/bar` so that it actually acts as a proxy to `~/mounts/bar`? In essence shadowing `~/foo/bar`.

That way if the host (Windows) shares `foo` on it's network, it's clients will be able to access the content of `foo/bar` and the host VB machine would indirectly read/write to `~/mounts/bar` while pointing at `~/foo/bar`. Actually the application expects one base data directory not multiple.

Comment: You could mount it as a CIFS share. Or, are you looking for a [symlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808394/hard-link-and-symbolic-links-in-unix)?

Comment: symlink didn't work, returned some read-only file-system error. Are we allowed to have nested mounting? i.e. mount inside a mounted location. Haven't tried it.

Comment: Yes. As long as the mount point is an empty folder, **or** a [UnionFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS).

Comment: I can't comment on that until I've tested it. Would it do if the mount point is a broken symlink?

Comment: Nope it doesn't `mount: mount point bar is a symbolic link to nowhere`. `bar` is an arbitrary broken symlink I created.

Comment: A broken symlink is not a valid [mount point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29).